# Shell script to compare multiple files

Tags: shell, awk, diff, difference, comm

I am comparing two files in my script. using the command

```
comm -3 123.txt 321.txt"
```

These two files 123 and 321 has only numeric content.

Also I use

```
diff -ibw abc.txt cba.txt
```

These files abc and cba  has alphanumeric content

If there is no mismatch no output is printed can you help me how to write a condition as below.

If there is no difference I need to print `files match` 
If there is a difference I want to print `mismatch found` along with the mismatched output.

Comment: from `man diff`, exit status is `0  if inputs are the same, 1 if different` .. you can use that... also, if you use `-s` option, you'll get a message that files are identical when inputs are same

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy in shell script. When you execute `diff` command in Unix/Linux it return `0` if no difference and if difference then it returns `1` and you can check that in system variable `$?`.

For example:-

```
#!/bin/bash

diff abc.txt cba.txt  > /dev/null 2>&1 #not to print the out put of from diff command

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "files match"  
else
   echo "mismatch found"
fi
```

But if you are using different command just check the exit value with `echo $?` while successful and while not successful and change your `if` condition accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If using `GNU bash`, use built-in list operators `&&` and `||` to do that.

```
diff -ibw abc.txt cba.txt &>/dev/null && echo "Files Match" || echo "Files do not match"
```

From `man bash`:

> AND  and OR lists are sequences of one of more pipelines separated by the `&&` and `││` control operators, respectively.  AND and
>   OR lists are executed with left associativity.  An AND list has the form
>
> ```
>           command1 && command2
> ```
>
> `command2` is executed if, and only if, `command1` returns an exit status of zero.
>
> ```
>    An OR list has the form
>
>           command1 ││ command2
> ```
>
> `command2` is executed if and only if `command1` returns a non-zero exit status.  The return status of AND and OR lists is the exit status
>   of the  last
>          command executed in the list.